# Javascript getters/setters to ES3

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, ecmascript-3

I have the following function which I'm trying to implement into Photoshop (uses Javascript ES3 for scripting). How could I write this to be ES3 compatible?

```
function VParabola(s){
    this.cEvent = null;
    this.parent = null;
    this._left = null;
    this._right = null;
    this.site = s;
    this.isLeaf = (this.site != null);
}

VParabola.prototype = {
    get left(){
        return this._left;
    },
    get right(){
        return this._right;
    },
    set left(p){
        this._left = p;
        p.parent = this;
    },
    set right(p){
        this._right = p;
        p.parent = this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does your environment support `Object.defineProperty`? Or `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__`?

Comment: I believe Photoshop is limited to ES3 - I am getting `Object.defineProperty is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, what about the other one? It's a non-standard ES3 extension.

Comment: Tried writing `Object.__defineGetter__('right', function() { return right; });` inside the VParabola function. Still not a function. I don't know if I'm writing this right.

Comment: Should be `VParabola.prototype.__defineGetter__('left', function() { return this._left; });` (outside the constructor, of course)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I just determined that independently :) - works in browser, but not in ExtendScript for Photoshop - not a function. Is there any escape from this?

Comment: Does ExtendScript support getter/setter properties at all? You might need to resort back to normal methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181557/discussion-between-cristianc-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in your constructor function like

```
function VParabola(s){
    this.cEvent = null;
    this.parent = null;
    var left = null;
    var right = null;
    this.site = s;
    this.isLeaf = (this.site != null);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'right', {
        get: function () {
            return right;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            right = value;
        }
    })

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'left', {
        get: function () {
            return left;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            left = value;
        }
    })

 }
```

Comment: The defined properties shouldn't have the `_` prefix. Good answer.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` is ES5, so I doubt this works?

Comment: This doesn't work - `Object.defineProperty` is not a function.